# Implementing Facebook-like previous and next image effects using jQuery

Tags: jquery

These two div tags both display previous and next image from actual large image:

```
<div class="alignleft"><a href="1005.php"><img width="50" height="50" src="thumb-98.jpg" class="previous"></a></div>

<div class="alignright"><a href="1051.php"><img width="50" height="50" src="thumb-100.jpg" class="next"></a></div>
```

It displays the actual large image:

```
<img width="600" height="800" src="99-600x800.jpg" class="large-image">
```

I was thinking (a la Facebook) on action hover of large image, show the hidden next and previous linked thumbnails in the vertical center of the large image, previous close to the left side and next at the right side.

How can this be done?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion Sparky672. I just did it! It will never happens again. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

use jquery light box plugin 
    http://leandrovieira.com/projects/jquery/lightbox/

Comment: No, because it is not a group of images, is more simple, previous and next are thumbnails that redirects or reloads the page to the previous or next image view.

Comment: @José Pablo Orozco Marín:  You explicitly stated that you wanted something like on Facebook and a lightbox fits that.